# Extending a graph struct in c

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, struct

**My problem:** I have a graph made of `node` struct

```
struct node {
   node *n1;
   node *n2;
}
```

And I want to add some members to make a new struct `newNode`

```
struct newNode {
   newNode *n1;
   newNode *n2;
   newNode *n3; // new member
   int      a;  // new member
}
```

I want to keep the original "node connections" in the graph so that I can do

```
newNode *n;
n->n1->n2...
```

just like

```
node *n;
n->n1->n2...
```

where n1 (or n2) of the two structs represent the same node in the graph, while I can also do

```
newNode *n;
n->n1->a...
n->n1->n3...
```

It's tricky to modify the `node` struct as it's defined in a big library.

**My idea** is to add one more member to `newNode` struct

```
struct newNode {
   node    *n; // added member
   newNode *n1;
   newNode *n2;
   newNode *n3;
   int      a;
}
```

First, I create a `newNode` `n_new` for each `node` `n`. Then I traverse every pair of `n_new`s, say n_new1 and n_new2, look at `n_new1->n` and `n_new2->n` to see whether there's a connection between them, that is, whether `n_new1->n->n1 == n_new2->n`, or `n_new1->n->n2 == n_new2->n` or vice versa. If so I make `n_new1->n1 = n_new2`, or `n_new1->n2 = n_new2` or vice versa.

But the time complexity is `O(#node^2)`. Inefficient.

Any other ideas?

**P.S.** The graph is a reduced-ordered binary decision diagram.

Comment: you want a graph with new_node and node in them?

Comment: @user3125280 I want to keep the original nodes (and the connections), but also add some new nodes. The two structures should represent the same graph at first.

Comment: Ah I get it now - you want to basically copy a graph structure. What you have described is indeed a very slow way. I recommend you google copying a graph data structure or similar. Basically to copy a node, create a n_new, then fill its n1 and n2 with the copy of the old node's n1 and n2. You will need a mechanism to determine which node's you have already copied (probably you will need a bst or hash here, unless you can change node's source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy recursively, creating a new new_node each time you encounter a new node (read that carefully). This will be a complete copy of the original graph, structurally identical but using different memory.

To determine if we have already copied a node, we keep a list of the ones we have copied (and their copies) in a BST that maps node* to new_node*.

You can find many BST implementations out there. There is one in the stl c++ library, for example and I think glibc, and so on.

The code will look like this:

```
struct node {
   node *n1;
   node *n2;
}

struct new_node {
   node *n1;
   node *n2;
   newNode *n3; // new member
   int      a;  // new member
}

new_node* GraphCopy (node* start)
{
    new_node* n_new;

    if(!start) return NULL;

    n_new = malloc(sizeof(new_node));

    //Add start.n1 and start.n2 to a bst here
    //with keys of node* and vals of new_node*

    TreeInsert(start, n_new)

    if(IsInTree(start->n1))
        n_new->n1 = TreeFind(start->n1);
    else
        n_new->n1 = GraphCopy(start->n1);

    //repeat for n2

 }
```

Complexity would be linear if there were no tree, so its still quite quick. (It would be more linear with a hash table, for example.)

(The tree would map node* to their copies.)